# Trouble importing csv file with ruby CSV Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use Ruby's csv module to import the records contained in a csv file to my local table in a Ruby on Rails 3 application.

The table was created through the creation of model Movie.

Here is what I've been executing in console:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach('public/uploads/VideoTitles2.csv') do |row|
    record = Movie.new(
        :media_format   => row[0], 
        :title          => row[1], 
        :copies_at_home => row[2], 
        :order          => row[3]
    )
    record.save
end
```

The rows of the csv file match (in data type) the columns they're being passed into. Here is a shortened version of the csv file (VideoTitles2.csv) I'm attempting to import:

```
"DVD","LEAP OF FAITH",1,1
"DVD","COCOON",1,2
"DVD","TITANIC",1,3
```

where each record is separated by \n I believe. This csv file was exported from Access and its original file extension was .txt. I've manually changed it to .csv for sake of the import.

The problem is that, after executing the above lines in rails console, I get the following output:

```
=> nil
```

The import doesn't seem to happen. If anyone has an idea as to how I could remedy this I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay there were two things I had wrong:

1. The exported csv file should not have quotations around the strings - I just removed them.
2. Thanks to tokland, the record.save! was necessary (as opposed to the record.save I was doing) - validation errors *were* preventing the records from being created.

So to conclude, one could just create the following function after creating the model/table Movie:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :media_format, :title, :copies_at_home, :order
  require 'csv'

  def self.import_movies()
    CSV.foreach('public/uploads/movies.csv') do |row|
        record = Movie.new(
            :media_format   => row[0], 
            :title          => row[1], 
            :copies_at_home => row[2], 
            :order          => row[3]
        )
        record.save!  
    end
  end
end
```

Where movies.csv looks like the following:

```
Blu-ray, Movie 1, 1, 1
DVD, Movie 2, 1, 2
Blu-ray, Movie 3, 1, 3
```

then call this function in console as such:

```
Movie.import_movies()
```

and, as expected, all that would be returned in the console would be:

```
=> nil
```

Check your index view (if you've created one) and you should see that the records were successfully imported into the movies table.

Comment: no control of repeated movies? also, it's good etiquette for a function to return something meaningful. Maybe the array of newly created movies? maybe just the number? note also that new + save! = create!

Comment: yeah very true; I was using it as a one time thing

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the problem. This code snippet returns `nil` because `CSV.foreach` returns `nil`, but this is no indication if the loop is run or not. Did you checked if any `Movie` was created? did you include any debug lines to follow the process?

You may want to check the output of `record.save` (or call `record.save!`), maybe validations errors are preventing the record from being created. Also, if you want the loop to return the created records, you can write this (Ruby >= 1.8.7):

```
require 'csv'

records = CSV.foreach('public/uploads/VideoTitles2.csv').map do |media_format, title, copies_at_home, order|     
    Movie.create!({
        media_format: media_format, 
        title: title, 
        copies_at_home: copies_at_home, 
        order: order,
    })
end
```

Comment: well the model/table movie already exists (i created it ahead of time). however i verified that none of the records were added. as a matter of fact, it resulted in a standard scaffolded controller/view throwing an error